# What does the code at the start of each Really Big Sky game mean?

Tags: really-big-sky

At the start of each Really Big Sky game a code is flashed onto the middle of the screen briefly, before disappearing.

[image]

The code appears to be random, and consists of names, numbers and letters. However, it's significance does not appear to be explained anywhere. What does it mean?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Really Big Sky developer here :)
The code is an interpretation of the random generation seed for the universe or "level". It displays the initial colours for the background, how strong bosses are, how frequently black holes appear... etc!